# How can I list folders in a directory except "." and ".." using C?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I can list files and folders. But I want to remove . and .. from the list.

I used some code that I found in Stack Overflow.

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
if ((dir = opendir ("/home/arda/things")) != NULL) {
  while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
    printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
  }
  closedir (dir);
} else {
  perror ("");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good exercise to do by yourself:

- Find the spot where the entry name gets printed
- Find the variable that represents the name of the entry
- Add an `if` statement around the printing code
- In the `if` condition, compare the first character of name to `'.'` character
- If the string is `".."` or `"."`, skip printing.

The actual fix will take a single line. Comparing strings is done using `strcmp`, i.e.

```
if (strcmp(a, "..") == 0 || strcmp(a, ".") == 0) ...
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it but it says I can't compare struct dirent and something else.

Comment: @betseg You need to compare the first character, which is `ent->d_name[0]`

Comment: This will ignore all files that start with '.' -- not just '.' and '..'

Comment: @JohnHascall You are right, using `strcmp` is a more robust approach here. Thanks!

Comment: How do I do this "a"?

Comment: @betseg `a` is a string that you want to compare. In your case that's `ent->d_name`, so you'll have `if (strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
if ((dir = opendir ("/home/arda/things")) != NULL) {
  while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
    if (ent->d_name[0] == '.') {
        if (ent->d_name[1] == '\0') continue;
        if (ent->d_name[1] == '.') {
            if (ent->d_name[2] == '\0') continue;
        }
    }
    printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
  }
  closedir (dir);
} else {
  perror ("");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```